# NHibernate, QueryOver returning list with list property

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have classes like:

```
public class A : BaseTableFields
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<B> propB { get; set; }
}

public class B : BaseTableFields
{
    public virtual A propA { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<C> propC { get; set; }
}

public class C : BaseTableFields
{
    public virtual B propB { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<D> propD { get; set; }
}
```

So each of my class has one to many relation to class below of it.
How to write the most effecient query, that I receive List of type A (List listOfA) containing records in listOfA.propB and also the listOfA.propB having all of the referencing records in listOfA.propB.propC and so on.

Please help.

Let's assume for the start that:

```
var list = Session.QueryOver<A>().Where(x=>x.Name == "test").List().ToList();
```

returns me list with 3 elements of type A, but its property propB is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the 'Fetch' or 'FetchMany' functions in the NHibernate LINQ provider.  Examples are in [this article](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/08/nhibernate-linq-eager-fetching.html) for what it actually does and it shows the SQL it will generate.

Working off your example that would result like this:

```
var list = Session.QueryOver<A>()
                  .Where(x => x.Name == "test")
                  .FetchMany(x => x.propB)
                  .ThenFetchMany(x => x.propC)
                  .ToList();
```

If this is still causing you issues, then there may be a problem with your mapping files between the one to many relationships of the entities.

Comment: I've found mistakes in my mapping, but your answer helped me as well. It works if you replace QueryOver<>() with Query<>() and delete List() method, as NHibernate LINQ doesn't support this, simply ToList() is enough :) 
Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Glad I could help- the mappings usually cause the most issues for me and my coworkers if even one small thing is incorrect.